# Grep/SED/AWK for specific path ending with a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a list of paths, but I only care about certain ones. for example.

```
/nwsys/release/conf/reu/xprofd.cfg4
/nwsys/release/conf/save/xprofd.cfg.rtcr1
/nwsys/release/conf/amcxml4.conf
```

How do I return from that only /nwsys/release/conf/anyfile.anyextension

`grep "/nwsys/release/conf/"`

Comment: So far you have 3 different answers from people who all interpreted your question/requirements differently from each other. Post some concrete sample input and expected output to clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
awk -F/ '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$NF}' OFS=/ file
/nwsys/release/conf/xprofd.cfg4
/nwsys/release/conf/xprofd.cfg.rtcr1
/nwsys/release/conf/amcxml4.conf
```

Change path to three levels for all file.

---

Or is it this you are looking for:

```
awk -F/ 'NF<6' file
/nwsys/release/conf/amcxml4.conf
```

Prints lines that has path with 3 levels.

Comment: Ahem - you said you wanted to match `/nwsys/release/conf/anyfile.anyextension`. Testing for `NF<6` does not check that the file name contains a `.` followed by an extension, nor does it exclude `/bin/ls`.

Comment: Totally agree with @EdMorton How is `NF<6` related to `anyfile.anyextension` requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use egrep:

```
egrep '/nwsys/release/conf/.*\.' file
/nwsys/release/conf/reu/xprofd.cfg4
/nwsys/release/conf/save/xprofd.cfg.rtcr1
/nwsys/release/conf/amcxml4.conf
```

Where:

```
cat file
/nwsys/release/conf/reu/xprofd.cfg4
/nwsys/release/conf/save/xprofd.cfg.rtcr1
/nwsys/release/conf/amcxml4.conf
/nwsys/release/conf/anything
```

Comment: @TheHad - what the heck are you looking at? anubhava's script won't produce the same output as the other answers from your sample input - no matter which is correct, they can't **all** "work"!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ egrep '^/nwsys/release/conf/[^/]+\.[^/]+$' file
/nwsys/release/conf/amcxml4.conf
```

Comment: @TheHad - really THINK about what you're doing here. What my script does is completely different from whet Jotne's script does and will produce wildly different output depending on what your input file contains. Just because 2 scripts produce the same output for a 3-line sample input does not mean they both actually do what you want in the general case.